# How to find coefficients in MATLAB using polyfitn?

Tags: matlab, equation

I'm given data for x,y, and z. I am trying to fit a set of data into a model of functional form as described below:

`z(x, y) = c0 + c1.* exp(-(c2 .* x)) + c3.* (y.^1)`

where `c0`, `c1`, `c2` and `c3` are the coefficients to be found.

I tried John D'Errico's [polyfitn()](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/34765-polyfitn). But, how can I fit my proposed model in this function?.

% So far I have tried

```
clc

x= [1 .. 60];

y= [0.001 .. 0.8];

z= [0.996297743 .. 0.095331687];

model= c0 + c1.* exp(-(c2 .* x)) + c3.* (y.^1);

p = polyfitn([x(:),y(:)], z(:),  'model')
```

% Here x,y are independent variables and z is dependent variable. 
I'm not sure how to pass the arguments.

Comment: John D'Errico's (a.k.a woodchips) os very responsive on the FEX of this file http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/34765-polyfitn, If I were you, I'd just ask him. Tell him also SO matlab users miss him...

Comment: It looks like you are trying to fit a non-polynomial function, but `polyfitn` is for polynomial models. The `model` parameter allows you to specify which terms of the polynomial will be non-zero, but does not allow non-polynomial terms to be used.

Comment: @David Can u suggest some other method to fit data using this proposed model?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In my eyes there is no need for an external tool, the convenient `cftool` can help you in most of the cases. It will generate you the following function:

```
function [fitresult, gof] = expfit(x, y, z)

[xData, yData, zData] = prepareSurfaceData( x, y, z );

% Set up fittype and options.
ft = fittype( 'c0 + c1.* exp(-(c2 .* x)) + c3.* (y.^1);', 'independent', {'x', 'y'}, 'dependent', 'z' );
opts = fitoptions( ft );
opts.Display = 'Off';
opts.Lower = [-Inf -Inf -Inf -Inf];
opts.StartPoint = [0.0975404049994095 0.278498218867048 0.546881519204984 0.957506835434298];
opts.Upper = [Inf Inf Inf Inf];

% Fit model to data.
[fitresult{1}, gof(1)] = fit( [xData, yData], zData, ft, opts );

% Plot fit with data.
figure( 'Name', 'untitled fit 1' );
h = plot( fitresult{1}, [xData, yData], zData );
legend( h, 'untitled fit 1', 'z vs. x, y', 'Location', 'NorthEast' );
% Label axes
xlabel( 'x' );
ylabel( 'y' );
zlabel( 'z' );
grid on
```

Finally you just need a script to evaluate your fitobject:

```
[res,gof] = expfit(x,y,z)
% gives you the coeffcients
coeffvalues(res{1})
```

---

**The short version (without additional function and plot) would be:**

```
[xData, yData, zData] = prepareSurfaceData( x, y, z );
functionToFit = 'c0 + c1.* exp(-(c2 .* x)) + c3.* (y.^1);';
ft = fittype( functionToFit, 'independent', {'x', 'y'}, 'dependent', 'z' );
fitobj = fit( [xData, yData], zData, ft );
coeffvalues( fitobj{1} )
```

---

Be aware that for 2-dimensional fits you need to use `prepareCurveData` instead of `prepareSurfaceData`. These are Matlab built-in functions somehow similiar to `meshgrid`, but especially "prepared" for curve/surface fits.

Comment: I actually don't have any idea about prepareCurveData and prepareSurfaceData at the moment! :(

Comment: well these are built-in functions. You don't have to care about them. If you're interested you can type `which prepareSurfaceData` in the command line and it will show you where it is located. If you don't want to use these function, you need to get back to Rody's solution, which (I guess) internally does the same. It's a little shorter once you have done the substitution. And also try out the `cftool`, you can try everything out, you see the results immediately and if you like it you can "generate code"

Answer (score 2):

You have a model that is not a polynomial, and it can also not be converted to a polynomial that `polyfitn` can solve.

To see this, re-write your equation. Make the substitution `u = exp(x)`, so that

```
z(ln(u), y) = c0 + c1·u^(-c2) + c3·y
```

This is a 2 dimensional polynomial with degree `-c2` for `u` and degree 1 for `y`.

`polyfitn` is not designed to solve for unknown and non-integer powers of the independent variables; it solves only (well, mostly) for the *coefficients*. In your case, it would solve for `c0`, `c1` and `c3` if `c2` is known.

What I would do is the folllowing:

```
%// function that computes the sum-of-squares for some estimate
model = @(c) sum((c(1) + c(2)*exp(-c(3)*x) + c(4)*y - z).^2);

%// optimize the fit 
C = fminsearch(model, [1 1 1 1]) %// NOTE: random starting values
```

With these two lines of code, I get

```
%// c0             c1             c2            c3
C = 2.3445e-001    8.4158e-001    1.5817e-001   -1.5584e-001
```

which looks pretty reasonable if I plot the model and the data, and the differences.

If you have the optimization toolbox, the following might be a bit more robust:

```
%// function that computes the difference of the model to the data
model = @(c) c(1) + c(2)*exp(-c(3)*x) + c(4)*y - z;

%// optimize the fit 
C = lsqnonlin(model, [1 1 1 1]) %// NOTE: random starting values
```

Answer (score 0):

Assume you have an independent variable C and a Dependent variable D with data and a function for D=f(C) as defined by ft. This works great:

```
ft = fittype('a*log(C)+b*cos(C)+c*exp(C)','independent','C','dependent','D');

fitobj = fit( x, D, ft );
KC=coeffvalues( fitobj )

plot(fitobj,C,D);
% 
txt = ['D= ' num2str(KC(1)) ' ln(C)' '+' num2str(KC(2))  ' cos(C)' '+'  num2str(KC(3))  ' exp(C)' ];
  annotation('textbox','String',txt,'FitBoxToText','on');
```